# Python3 toggle between two strings

Tags: string, python-3.x, toggle

Is there a more elegant way to toggle between two strings or integers in Python 3?

```
x={"A":"B", "B":"A"}[x]
```

The values can be non-boolean, like string or integer.
Let's suppose that we want to toggle between "A" and "B" and the variable name is x.

In other words: if `x = "A"` then the result should be `x = "B"` and if `x = "B"` then the result should be `x = "A"`.

**input:**

```
x="B"
```

**output:**

```
x="A"
```

Comment: what is the output you want to achieve ?

Comment: if x ="A" then the result should be x="B" and if x="B" then the result should be X="A"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a dict is already pretty smart. Here is an alternative:

```
x = 'B' if x == 'A' else 'A'
```

Comment: Goswin, I like your solution too. which one do you think makes the code more readable?

Comment: I think the "if" is better because it will recover from an invalid value.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like that:

```
def toggle(x):
    x['A'], x['B'] = x['B'], x['A']

x = {'A': 'B', 'B': 'A'}
```

or that:

```
def toggle(x):
    x.update(dict(zip(x.keys(), list(x.values())[::-1])))

x = {'A': 'B', 'B': 'A'}

print(x)
toggle(x)
print(x)
toggle(x)
print(x)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'A': 'B', 'B': 'A'}
{'A': 'A', 'B': 'B'}
{'A': 'B', 'B': 'A'}
```